# Autofill functionality for DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, autofill

I have one interesting requirement for data grid. By dragging the column cell the data in the cell should be copied to the below column cell like how we do in the MS Excel.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for copy down functionality for the data grid. This is done by the Datatables plugin which can be found here. I hope it would be useful some pple.

> http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/AutoFill/inputs.html